# Finding the javascript that changes a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I am trying to find the part of the JS where a certain element is being changed. I have looked around and I can't find a way to see how those events are handled.

The scenario is: there is a hidden field with a certain value. When I submit the form, the value changes right before being submitted.

What i am looking for is the method that changes that value.

Any advice on how to approach this would be very helpful as I am not very good when it comes to JS. Oh, and it looks like the code is obfuscated so most of the function names are one letter .

Comment: Use the debugger.  Both chrome and firefox have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I use in these situations is to examine the HTML around the area that is being modified, note all possible ways that code could find the appropriate DOM elements (form names, id values, class names, etc...) and then look through the code to find where it might be querying the DOM to find the DOM element that is being changed using one of these identifiers.  Since the identifiers can't be obscured, they should be in the code in normal English the same as they appear in the HTML.

In addition, you can make a list of all event listeners that are being set in the code and pay particular attention to event listeners on any objects near the one being changed.  Since it's a form submission, you can look for the submit event or click event on a form submission button.

When you see event handlers that you aren't sure whether they are involved, you can simply set a breakpoint in them and see if their code is hit during the action you are investigating.  I often find it helpful to make my own copy of the code in my own editor and start adding code comments to it as I find out what something does or how it works.  This gives me more of a running knowledge base rather than having to just remember everything.  This is even more useful when the variable names have all been obscured.

Comment: I can see from the debugger where DOMSubtreeModified and DOMAttrModified are being called, but I can't find which funct is calling them in JS